# MongoDB returns wrong rows with $sort, $skip and $limit

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is the function I'm using

```
MyModel.aggregate([
  { $match: query },
  { $sort: { 'createdAt': -1 } },
  { $skip: skip },
  { $limit: 10 }
  ], { allowDiskUse : true });
```

`query` is to filter the rows. `skip` is dynamic value based on pagination (i.e 0, 10, 20 ...). The problem is, the rows for each page in wrong. For instance, I can see a specific row in page 1,2,3,4 at the same time! some rows are missing as well.

Why is it happening?

Comment: If new documents are inserted between your queries, it will explain it...Another option is that the sort is not working as expected (typo)

Comment: No documents are constant while testing. No new entry.

Comment: Please provide a playground example

Comment: `createdAt` for many rows has the same value. is it a probability for `$sort` not to work properly?

Comment: Yes, there is no guarantee that it will sort the same way in every execution. You need to add additional field(s) to the sort, so that the sorting happens predictably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the key to this question is the information that you shared in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74529747/mongodb-returns-wrong-rows-with-sort-skip-and-limit#comment131563475_74529747):

> `createdAt` for many rows has the same value. is it a probability for `$sort` not to work properly?

It's not that the sort doesn't "work properly" necessarily, it's that it doesn't have enough information to sort deterministically each time. The value of `123` doesn't come before or after another value of `123` on its own. As [@Noel points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74529747/mongodb-returns-wrong-rows-with-sort-skip-and-limit#comment131564760_74529747), you need to provide an additional field(s) to your sort.

This is also covered [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#sort-consistency):

> MongoDB does not store documents in a collection in a particular order. When sorting on a field which contains duplicate values, documents containing those values may be returned in any order.
>
> If consistent sort order is desired, include at least one field in your sort that contains unique values. The easiest way to guarantee this is to include the `_id` field in your sort query.

This is because [the `_id` field is unique](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field). If you take that approach it would change your sort to:

```
{ $sort: { 'createdAt': -1, _id: 1 } },
```

Comment: Yes. That is exactly the way I implemented. Added `_id` as second sort parameter and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

the dynamic value based on pagination (i.e 0, 10, 20 ...) should be used for `limit`, then the `skip` should be `(page - 1 * limit)`

let say,

```
const limit = 10;
const page = 1;
const skip = (page - 1) * limit; // basically is 0

MyModel.aggregate([
  { $match: query },
  { $sort: { 'createdAt': -1 } },
  { $skip: skip },
  { $limit: limit }
  ], { allowDiskUse : true });
```

so your query will skip 0 data and start with the **first** result up **10th**

so if you page query is 2,

```
const limit = 10;
const page = 2;
const skip = (page - 1) * limit; // basically is 10

MyModel.aggregate([
  { $match: query },
  { $sort: { 'createdAt': -1 } },
  { $skip: skip },
  { $limit: limit }
  ], { allowDiskUse : true });
```

so your query will skip 10 data and start with the **11th** result up **20th**