# duplicated documents in the response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller, mern

i'm facing a problem here where i can see the same documents in different pages with the same id and everything in the response when testing in postman , i've checked the database and there is no duplicated documents , what could be causing the problem in here ?

```
async function getLeads(req, res) {

    try {
        
        const { 
            page = 0, 
            pageSize = 10, 
            sort = null, 
            search = "", 
            leadStatus = "", 
            industry = "", 
            agentId = "",
            endDate = "", 
            startDate = "",
        } = req.query
        
        const generateSort = () => {
            
            const sortParsed = JSON.parse(sort)
            
            const sortFormatted = {
                [sortParsed.field]: (sortParsed.sort = 'asc' ? 1 : -1)
            }
            
            return sortFormatted;
        }
        
        const sortFormatted = Boolean(sort) ? generateSort() : { createdAt: -1 }
        
        // console.log(leadStatus);
        // console.log(new Date("2023-07-13") > new Date("2000-07-11"))
        const leadsQuery = {
            $or: [
                { PhoneNumberCombined: { $regex: new RegExp(search) } },
                { ExecutiveFirstName: { $regex: new RegExp(search) } },
                { Email: { $regex: new RegExp(search) } },
            ],
            Agent: agentId !== "" ? new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(agentId) : { $exists: true },
            createdAt: {
                $gt: startDate !== "" ? new Date(startDate) : new Date("2000-01-01"),
                $lte: endDate !== "" ? new Date(endDate) : new Date("3000-03-03"),
            },
            LeadStatus: leadStatus !== "" ? leadStatus : { $exists: true },
        };
        
        if (industry !== "") {
            console.log("industry: ",industry);
            leadsQuery.Industry = industry;
        }
        
        const leads = await Lead.find(leadsQuery)
            .sort(sortFormatted)
            .skip(page * pageSize)
            .limit(pageSize)
            .populate({ path: 'Agent', select: 'FirstName LastName' });

        const totalLeads = await Lead.countDocuments({
            PhoneNumberCombined: { $regex: search }
        })

        const agents = await User.find({
            Role: "agent"
        }).select(' FirstName LastName ')

        res.status(200).json({
            leads: leads,
            agents: agents,
            total: totalLeads
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            'error': error,
            'errorMassage': 'something went wrong in get all leads'
        })
    }
}
```

i've tried everything but still facing the same problem

sample documents :

```
{
        "_id": "64d2acb05ea3ee328798ad48",
        "DateListProduced": "08/07/2023",
        "CompanyName": "Building Futures Marketing LLC",
        "MailingAdress": "100 W Hoover Ave # 103-618",
        "MailingCity": "Mesa",
        "MailingState": "AZ",
        "MailingZipCode": "85210",
        "ExecutiveLastName": "",
        "ExecutiveFirstName": "",
        "ExecutiveGender": "",
        "ExecutiveTitle": "",
        "PhoneNumberCombined": "(480) 382-7039",
        "LocationSalesVolumeRange": "$500,000-1 Million",
        "SICCodeDescription1": "Smoke Shops & Supplies",
        "LeadStatus": "New",
        "Email": "",
        "Agent": {
            "_id": "64c95c8dae03f14f3a9ffce3",
            "FirstName": "haboub",
            "LastName": "habiyb"
        },
        "Notes": [],
        "Calls": [],
        "Industry": "ISAM",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdAt": "2023-08-08T20:59:28.592Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-08-08T20:59:28.592Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "64d2acb05ea3ee328798ad47",
        "DateListProduced": "08/07/2023",
        "CompanyName": "Bullhead Vape Fort Mohave",
        "MailingAdress": "4470 S Highway 95 # 15",
        "MailingCity": "Fort Mohave",
        "MailingState": "AZ",
        "MailingZipCode": "86426",
        "ExecutiveLastName": "",
        "ExecutiveFirstName": "",
        "ExecutiveGender": "",
        "ExecutiveTitle": "",
        "PhoneNumberCombined": "(928) 299-5112",
        "LocationSalesVolumeRange": "",
        "SICCodeDescription1": "Smoke Shops & Supplies",
        "LeadStatus": "New",
        "Email": "",
        "Agent": {
            "_id": "64c95c8dae03f14f3a9ffce3",
            "FirstName": "haboub",
            "LastName": "habiyb"
        },
        "Notes": [],
        "Calls": [],
        "Industry": "ISAM",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdAt": "2023-08-08T20:59:28.592Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-08-08T20:59:28.592Z"
    },
```

query predicate values

```
const queryPredicates = {
page: 0,
pageSize: 10, 
sort: { field: 'CompanyName', sort: 'asc' },
leadStatus: "New",
search:"",
agentId: "",
industry: "Food",};
```

Comment: Is your sort (always) on a unique (set of) field(s)? Do you have sample documents and query predicate values that we can reproduce the problem with?

Comment: thank you so much for responding , i edited the question , i added some sample documents and a query .

Comment: Looks like you aren't supplying a unique sort which is likely the problem. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74533630/20042973) for more info