# Getting duplicate records when using skip, limit, and sort with MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following query which I am using to paginate the response with an increment of 15. While iterating through the paginated results, I am seeing some duplicate orderNumbers that was already seen in the previous pages and it happens intermittently only, sometimes earlier in the paginated results and sometimes later.

```
db.SomeTable.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            customerNumber: "XXXXX",
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            orderPlacedDate: -1,
            orderNumber: -1
        },
    },
    {
        $skip: 15,
    },
    {
        $limit: 15,
    }
]);
```

Since order placedDate is just a string in our database (for example: "20231012") and can have multiple duplicates. After reading the MongoDB documentation below, I went ahead and added orderNumber together with orderPlacedDate since orderNumber is always unique.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#std-label-sort-aggregation-consistent-sorting

I also tried changing orderNumber with _id to see what will happen but the duplicate results kept appearing.

Any idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: Sounds like you've taken the first step to [make the sort unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74529747/mongodb-returns-wrong-rows-with-sort-skip-and-limit/74533630#74533630). The only other thing that really jumps to mind: is the dataset changing?

Comment: The table that I am aggregating on is a collection that stores the document i.e. OrderHistory and there is a chance that a new OrderHistory is added for the customer that I am querying but I have ran my test script multiple times and I see the duplicate every time I test. @user20042973

Comment: is your _id an ObjectId() ? do you experience it with just sorting by _id if it is an ObjectId() ?

Comment: What is your test script? What is sample data that is problematic? What is the duplicate that you are seeing (and how are you determining that it is a duplicate)? How can we reproduce so that we can troubleshoot and assist?