# MongoDB aggregation with $match $skip $limit and order guarantee

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, match, limit, skip

Does the following aggregation guarantee a default ordering for the documents assuming that the $match returns unique documents? Or we always have to include a sort step to have consistent results across pages?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$match:{...}},
   {$skip:700},
   {$limit:100}
]}
```

Comment: No. You need the `$sort`. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74529747/mongodb-returns-wrong-rows-with-sort-skip-and-limit) might give you some more (not so relevant) information.

Comment: In my case the $match returns unique values, whereas in the referred post above they are sorting by a non-unique field. Are you sure we are talking about the same use case?

Comment: Sorry that that link doesn't help much, but you may still need the `$sort`. It is because without `$sort`, you have no guarantee on the return order. Newly inserted documents may disrupt the natural order and cause inconsistent sorting